# android button drawableleft icon inside triangle shape

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-button

I have drawn a triangle on button left side using drawableleft (@drawable/triangle.xml). I need to place an icon inside that triangle. But the code below it shows left to drawn triangle. Thanks in advance

triangle.xml

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="13%"
            android:pivotY="-38%"
            android:toDegrees="45" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <size android:width="135dp" android:height="135dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/yellow" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
     <item android:drawable="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Button in layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sample_button"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/triangle"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:text="@string/sample"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the drawable as background.

```
    android:background="@drawable/triangle"
```

Comment: Its showing but if i set button background color programmatically. It overrides the triangle shape. only icon and color is visible not triangle.